# One liner solution to matching lines in one file to another file

Tags: bash

Similar questions were raised before, but I am interested specificially in a Unix one liner solution.

I would like to be able to quickly match lines of one file to the lines in a second file on a command line.

So, for example, my first file `foo` is:

```
$ cat foo
apple
orange
beer
bat
```

and the second file, `bar`, is:

```
$ cat bar
beer 25
bat 78
nothing 90
```

And now I want to match lines in `foo` to `bar` and print out the content of `bar` when there is a match. I have a slowww solution with a for loop and `grep` utility:

```
$ for l in $(cat foo); do grep $l bar; done
```

but maybe there is a faster way of doing the same task in a one-liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `grep`:

```
# long version
grep --fixed-strings --word-regexp --file=foo bar
# short version
grep -F -w -f foo bar
# mini version
grep -Fwffoo bar
```

### result

```
beer 25
bat 78
```

---

Comment: and of course, the ol-world version `fgrep -f foo bar`. Good luck to all!

Comment: Works like a charm, there is a lot to grep!

Answer (score 2):

If you can sort the files:

```
$ sort foo > foo.sorted
$ sort bar > bar.sorted
$ join -t ' ' foo.sorted bar.sorted
```

### result

```
bat 78
beer 25
```

Comment: I don't know yet how to make your solution into one-liner, but it works nicely too

Comment: It's one-liner if files are sorted ;-)